# When I knit in r-markdown it distorts my boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

When I run my boxplot in R-Studio, it outputs correctly, but when I use knit, it distorts one of the boxes:

Output in R-Studio:
[image]

Output in knit file:
[image]

This happens both in word and html formats. I messed arround with knits fig. size configs and ggplot2 w and h configs but the problem seems to be the device?

Plot code is as follows, This bug ocurred both on rmarkdown 1.8 and 1.9

````
```{r plotA3.route1, fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE}

ggplot(dfRoutes, aes(score, pAlpha)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = scoreBool))+ geom_smooth(method = "lm")

```
````

The question here is: how to have the correct graph on the .html file?

Comment: [have a look at how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This stays here as a token of my stupidity, for if someone somewhere does the same mistakes I did:

- The difference between knit and env versions was due to old env data preserved
- de skewedness of the second boxplot is because if there are only values arround "score" 1 on the DF, it will reduce bp width and reposition it so that is represented